# Nodejs os.uptime() return incorrect up-time value by millisecond

Tags: javascript, node.js, milliseconds, uptime

I want to convert server up-time to `days:hours:minutes:second`. I use from this code:

```
var os = require('os');
var uptime = os.uptime();
console.log(convertMS(uptime));
```

and use this code for convert time to days:

```
function convertMS(ms) {
  var d, h, m, s;
  s = Math.floor(ms / 1000);
  m = Math.floor(s / 60);
  s = s % 60;
  h = Math.floor(m / 60);
  m = m % 60;
  d = Math.floor(h / 24);
  h = h % 24;
  return { d: d, h: h, m: m, s: s };
};
```

but `uptime` variable return me a number like this `16051.8370378`. This is incorrect. What should I do?

Comment: What version of node are you using? Also note that `uptime` returns seconds, not milliseconds, so your initial division is not appropriate.

Comment: I'm using `v6.9.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speacial Thanks from @jcaron

In version `v6.9.4` uptime returns `seconds`. I made a mistake.

[v6.9.4 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/os.html#os_os_uptime)